# Unable to subscribe to router events in Aurelia (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

There's no reason this shouldn't be working:)

```
import {Router, RouterConfiguration} from 'aurelia-router';
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';
import {autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@autoinject
export class App {
  router: Router;
  ea: EventAggregator;
  navEvent: any;

  constructor(eventAggregator: EventAggregator) {
    this.ea = eventAggregator;
  }

  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.title = 'Intterra Management';
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'home'], name: 'home', moduleId: 'home', nav: false, title: '' },
      { route: 'logs', name: 'logs', moduleId: 'logs', nav: true, title: 'Logs' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }

  attached() {
    this.navEvent = this.ea.subscribe('router:navigation:complete', response => {
      localStorage['state'] = location.hash;
    });
  }

  detached() {
    this.navEvent.dispose();
  }
 ...
```

I verified the event is firing when when I navigate, but the subscribed function isn't being called. Any ideas?

Comment: you're going to have to provide the code where the event is firing. probably mispelled or something?

Answer (score 3):

Since the attached function is called after all of the routes and such are composed in, you are most likely subscribing to the event after the event is called. You should put this in your `activate` function.

```
activate() {
  this.navEvent = this.ea.subscribe('router:navigation:complete', response => {
    localStorage['state'] = location.hash;
  });
}

deactivate() {
  this.navEvent.dispose();
}
```

Comment: This seems right. The 'router:navigation:complete' event happens after the URL is changed & the router changes the DOM / view. It should be triggered immediately after the view updates.

Answer (score 0):

No sure if you have found a solution to your problem yet, but try using `this.ea` directly.

```
this.ea.subscribe("router:navigation:complete", response => {
    localStorage['state'] = location.hash; 
});
```

Not sure if subscribing to said event in your constructor might help?

Comment: Using `this.ea` directly would cause a performance problem. Removing the `this.navEvent = ` will cause multiple events to be stacked on top of each other, if the feature is repeatedly used. Thus degrading performance! It's important to to use `this.navEvent =` so that the subscription can be destroyed by the deactivate method. That method creates a singleton, where only 1 event runs whenever the feature is used repeatedly.